# Reduce brightness in Grub

Tags: grub2, display, brightness

I have a laptop whose buggy BIOS can't set display panel brightness to a previous lower value during POST. Every time the laptop boots , the POST screen is 100% bright.

I can refresh the brightness on the POST screen (and in the BIOS menu, and in the GRUB menu) to a previous lower value using Fn + F3 (XF86MonBrightnessUp) . Actually pressing this key makes the BIOS re-read the previous value and set to it. But, once the laptop is rebooted, it is 100% bright again till it enters the operating system.

Once the operating system is booted, the brightness is taken over by the graphics driver, which properly sets the brightness to a previous saved value in the OS.

So, my issue is 100% bright screen from POST to operating system, unless I use the Fn key every time.

So, Can GRUB2 somehow simulate the Fn brightness key press to refresh the brightness and make my panel dimmer? I need to simulate the key press of XF86MonBrightnessUp key once and then XF86MonBrightnessDown key once to not change the previous value.

Comment: I have no experience with GRUB, but in bootloaders I know it's no problem to set the backlight brightness. Wouldn't it be sufficient for you if the bootloader would do it?

Comment: I have no problem if the grub can set / change it. Since grub2 is the default on most linux distros , I have no experience with any other bootloader. But I would like to know and see if similar functionality is available in grub2 . Thanks.

Comment: Found the solution here, give a try:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/374677/full-brightness-and-keyboard-backligh-at-boot